# dynamic reconfigure not building proper cpp header

Tags: ros, driver, stereo, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to write a node for the Focus Robotics fpga stereo cam.  I copied the code from bumblebee2 package and modified it to take the stereo cam and publish to image messages and a stereo message.  My problem is with the dynamic reconfigure.  I copied the bumblebee2 config file and added some of my own.  It autogenerates the header file but it is full of errors like the following

```
In file included from /home/scott/ARA_Stack/fr_cam/cfg/cpp/fr_cam/Fr_camConfig.h:50:0,
                 from /home/scott/ARA_Stack/fr_cam/src/fr_cam.cpp:76:
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/driver_common/dynamic_reconfigure/include/dynamic_reconfigure/config_tools.h:14:22: error: ‘BoolParameter’ is not a member of ‘fr_cam::dynamic_reconfigure’
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/driver_common/dynamic_reconfigure/include/dynamic_reconfigure/config_tools.h:14:22: note: suggested alternative:
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/driver_common/dynamic_reconfigure/msg_gen/cpp/include/dynamic_reconfigure/BoolParameter.h:95:71: note:   ‘dynamic_reconfigure::BoolParameter’
```

I can build the bumblebee package without any errors.  What is going on?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12749/dynamic-reconfigure-not-building-proper-cpp-header/) by [wyosae67](https://answers.ros.org/users/1693/wyosae67/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2012-01-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

um I was missing a { in one of my header files.

---

Originally posted by [wyosae67](https://answers.ros.org/users/1693/wyosae67/) with karma: 76 on 2012-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1